# JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA SVN SSH configuration

Tags: svn, ssh, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to configure my JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA to integrate with SVN

I need to put in the authentication realm,

I already put it once, but I misspelled one letter, and now it wont let me change it

also I need to put in SSH credentials

if I create a new repository and try to checkout my project to that repository it asks me for username and password with no option to enter ssh credentials

how do I fix this ?

I tried looking on the jetbrains man pages, but nothing I can find there

Comment: Which specific JetBrains product are you using?  IntelliJ?  ReSharper?  RubyMine?

Answer (score 0):

for IntelliJ 13, open the settings and search for SSH (Version Control->Subversion), there is a button bottom left to "clear auth cache" for SVN, I did that and was able to reset information next time I did an update.  You probably alreadt know given you asked this a month ago, but I was looking for the same thing.